# How to make a program as a default program to open specific files in Visual Studio C++

Tags: c++, c, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, visual-c++

Actually, I have no idea about what is the title of my question, so I couldn't search on Google, first I need to know what to say to this problem.

Well, I have developed a application in Visual Studio C++ 2010,  in which 3D objects can be processed, so there is a function called Import Model which helps to import model.

What I want is, the user just right click on the object and press Open with [application name] or double click on it, and application should the get the path of that file and call the Import function. Same like we do with any MS word *.doc files, we double click on it and it gets open.

I want the same thing to make my software as a default program to open some specific files extension. When user double click on the model, it should open in my application.

Actually, I read something about argument parser, I don't know much about it. Is it what I need to look for ?

Thanks.

**Update 1:**

It is working Benjamin Lindley and others, but I am getting the following error before starting the application. The argument only passing through FLTK window. I have no idea from where this window comes? not even about these image options.. see the following picture please...

[image]

Comment: "File association" is probably a good term to search for

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"File association", as mentioned in the comments and answers, is off topic (in my opinion), and probably belongs on [Super User](https://superuser.com/).  But as a programmer, what do you have to do?  Well, when someone double clicks on a file that is associated with your program, the filename comes in as an argument to your main function, and you can process that however you like:

```
int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    // the name file that was used to open your program is stored in argv[1]
    if (argc == 2)
        DoSomethingWithFile(argv[1])
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this works, but I am getting one error, could you please tell from where this window comes which I have just added in my question.

Comment: @furqan: this might help; http://www.mail-archive.com/fltk@easysw.com/msg10715.html

Comment: You rock, awesome ;) .. I was just about to ask this on fltk forum, I was compiling my code with your answer, and it works like charm. Thanks alot. I will update my question with the answer.

Answer (score 3):

You need file association, for example, in a `.bat` file:

```
@ASSOC .3D=3DObject.File
@FTYPE 3DObject.File="C:\MyProjects\Release\myprog.exe" "%%1" %%*
```

This uses registry hive `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT`, and you might need write access to that, so "Run as Administrator".

Edit: As a programmer you could use the Registry APIs (`RegCreateKeyEx`,  `RegSetValueEx`, etc.) to add the association to `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT` yourself, but probably not worth the effort since it is probably only needed once.

Comment: Cool tip, I've only every done it with direct registry writes and never knew it could be done that way, but was enough of a skeptic to confirm and above does work.

Comment: How about to create a button which helps users to associate files with my software. So, do I need to called this subroutine to add the registry, and will it in run-time. because in run-time user will click the button and registry should be added and updated. Or is there any option in the deployment setup of MSI file to add the registry during the setup ?

Comment: @furqan: personally I would add that to the installation procedure.

Comment: Could you please explain me little bit how can I add in the installation procedure ? @cdarke

Comment: @furqan: sorry, not my area.

Comment: Its ok. Thanks a lot for your effort. :)

Comment: Here is [official document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/ftype)